# Тень для Layout

Tags: android, layout

Подскажите как реализовать такую тень у Layout-а

[image: shadow]

Comment: Используйте `cardview`

Comment: "android:elevation" у элемента верстки, вокруг которого должна отбрасываться тень

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поместите ваш layout в CardView (В данном случае у меня это ImageView), Укажите желаемый cardElevation. И будет Вам счастье.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="250dp"
app:cardElevation="5dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```